# Set schema for @Embedded tables in JPA annotation?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using JPA to persist my data and have one column that is `@embedded` and refers to a class that is `@embeddable`.

When my job runs the tables are created in the schema I specify via the `@table` annotation. But the data for the `@embeddable` objects are written in the default schema. I do not see any property to set the schema for the `@embeddable` tables.

Hope you can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be to add the annotation `@CollectionTable`.